# What is the purpose of setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled - AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine

I am starting to work with AndEngine and I see that some tutorials use `setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled` but don't explain its purpose.

Why I need to use this method together with `onAreaTouched`?
Should not be `onAreaTouched` enough and detect inside of it whether is DOWN or UP?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose of the method `setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled` is to be able to "Bind" the sprite/button/etc to a scene/hud.

For example, if you only use the `onAreaTouched` for a controller in a race game. When you click on gaz (action down) it accelerates and when you remove your finger ( action up ) decelerates. But what happens if you click and keep your finger and swipe ( move ) outside the button area?
In this case the button action up is not called and although your finger is no longer on the button the car still keeps accelerating.

Thus instead of managing this scenario manually, the `setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled` will handle this type of scenario for you

Source: AE developer

Comment: Add link to the source code: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2-AnchorCenter/src/org/andengine/entity/scene/Scene.java#312, see line 312 -> 327 -> 408.