# Andengine onAreaTouched TouchEvent not working - ACTION_OUTSIDE & ACTION_CANCEL

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have a simple problem. I have a button on the screen. I want isActionDown to push the button down, and isActionUp to push the button back up again and make my character jump. But the problem is if I push the button down and drag away from it, the button stays pushed down. I would like the button to push back up again if the user drags away from it.

How can I create the desired affect? isActionCancel doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
    private void addButton(){
    goB = new AnimatedSprite(240, 364, ResourceManager.getInstance().go_region, vbom){
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent event, final float x, final float y){


            if (event.isActionDown()){
                goB.animate(new long[]{ 250 }, new int[] { 1 }, true);
                /*if(event.isActionCancel()){
                    goB.animate(new long[]{ 250 }, new int[] { 0 }, true);
                }*/
            }
            if (event.isActionUp()){
                goB.animate(new long[]{ 250 }, new int[] { 0 }, true);
                fresh = true;
                playerBody.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 45), playerBody.getPosition());
            }


            if (event.isActionCancel() || event.isActionOutside()){
                goB.animate(new long[]{ 250 }, new int[] { 0 }, true);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    goB.setScale(3);

    registerTouchArea(goB);
    attachChild(goB);

    goB.animate(250);
}
```

I'm having the hardest time with this, and I've tried all sorts of variations of the code above. Please let me know if you have the solution.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the

```
setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
setTouchAreaBindingOnActionMoveEnabled(true);
```

functions

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Adding this above my code makes it so, when I press and hold the button and drag away, the button is still depressed. Upon my release, it activates as a actionup. Is it possible to use this so that moving the finger off the button allows the button to preform a third action (popping back up without making the character jump)?

Comment: Btw, these two lines of code are necessary . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754670/what-is-the-purpose-of-settouchareabindingonactiondownenabled-andengine

Comment: These lines changes anything?

Comment: Perhaps you could add the relevant content of the link you posted to your answer to provide some context for future visitors.

Comment: I added...setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true); & setTouchAreaBindingOnActionMoveEnabled(true); But now the problem has changed a little. When I push down and drag off, the button does not release. The button stays pushed until I let go which looks funny. I would like the button to only reset if I push down and release above it like a normal button you would encounter in reality.